# ios error terminating -[__NSArrayM setRoleHistorys:]:

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services

Im trying to make user role page that get data from login. I created the own delegate function to call the webservice but app getting crash due to-[__NSArrayM setRoleHistorys:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance.
Here is my code: in .m file :

```
- (void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
  nodeContent = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
}

- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
  arrayitems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
U serRoleDataParser *userroleParser = [[UserRoleDataParser alloc] init];
  // UserRole *currentStudent = (UserRole *) arrayitems;
NSString *Username = username.text;
NSLog(@"the String value%@",Username);
[userroleParser getUserHistoryForIndex:0 LoginId:username.text];
 NSLog(@"the String user value %@",username.text);
userroleParser.delegate = self;

}
- (void) didrecieveData : (NSArray *) userHistories forIndex :(int) index
 {
arrayitems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
UserRole *roles = (UserRole *) arrayitems;
roles.RoleHistorys = userHistories;
datadisplay.text = roles.role;
NSLog(@"the Success data%@", datadisplay.text);

}
```

in delegate file .h

```
 @interface UserRole : NSObject

@property (nonatomic,copy)  NSString *username;
 @property (nonatomic,copy)  NSString *role;
@property (nonatomic,copy)  NSString *empcode;

@property (nonatomic,copy)NSMutableArray * RoleHistorys;
@end
```

Dataparser.h file (delegate)

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
 #import "UserRole.h"

 @protocol UserRoleDataParserDelegate <NSObject>

 - (void) didrecieveData : (NSArray *) userHistories forIndex :(int) index ;

 @end

 @interface UserRoleDataParser : NSObject<NSXMLParserDelegate>
{
 NSMutableData *xmlData;
NSXMLParser *userroleParser;
NSMutableString *capturedString;
BOOL captureCharacters;
NSMutableArray *userHistories;
}

- (void) getUserHistoryForIndex : (int) index LoginId :(NSString*) loginId;

 @property (weak,nonatomic) id <UserRoleDataParserDelegate> delegate;
 @property (nonatomic) int index;

@end
```

am getting output in nslog but the app getting crash.

Answer (score 1):

This code isn't correct:

```
arrayitems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
UserRole *roles = (UserRole *) arrayitems;
```

You can't just cast an array to your custom class type (unless you have subclassed `NSMutableArray` and the instance is actually of the subclass type). You need to create an instance of or find the correct instance you want before you try to use it.

Comment: I can't tell what you need to do. Perhaps just `UserRole *roles = [[UserRole alloc] init]`. It isn't clear as you don't look to already have one and you don't do much with the one you're trying to use (you don't store it)...

Answer (score 0):

You create NSMutableArray and you cast it to UserRole object, after that you try to save data in that: `roles.RoleHistorys` :

```
arrayitems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
UserRole *roles = (UserRole *) arrayitems;
roles.RoleHistorys = userHistories; //<- Error happened here
```

So you try to save data by calling selector `setRoleHistorys` on object of type NSMutableArray which you cannot do because NSMutableArray doesn't contain that property.

Comment: Yes and I explained why. Probably you want to add UserRole object to the array and after that you want to get the data from the array and change the object. But for now you just to try change the object on NSMutableArray which won't work because there is no property you want to amend.